# How to add external NTFS drive to Google Cloud Engine app?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Since using docker takes up a lot of space for images, I would like to attach an external hard drive to my 10GB instance Ubuntu VM. However, I've added a blank disk and attached it, but I end up with this message when I type "fdisk -l":
Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table.

How do I create an external NTFS drive and mount it to my filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as on any other Ubuntu instance, once you've attached an unformatted or unsuitably-formatted drive... one good set of instructions is for example at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive .

To do it manually, run, as root (`sudo bash` for example):

```
$ apt-get install ntfsprogs
$ df -k  # just to check nothing is mounted on /dev/sdb...
$ # umount /dev/sdb  if df -k shows something mounted there
$ fdisk  # to fix the partition table, see http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk
$ # if you need a tutorial, http://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/
$ mkfs.ntfs -f /dev/sdb1  # if you're in a hurry, or
$ # mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1   # if you have all the time in the world
```

Incidentally, this is a system administration question, not a software development one, so you might be happier asking it over at serverfault -- we do monitor the google-cloud-platform there, too.

Two side issues -- (1) why NTFS?  You're unlikely to be using this PD with Windows, so a native Linux file system might be preferable...  (2) what does this have to do with google-app-engine?  Did you mistype that tag meaning actually google-compute-engine instead...?

Comment: yes should be compute engine instead! i get confused with their nomenclature

Comment: @Allen, I understand the confusion -- sorry, it's hard to get memorable names for many products through legal and marketing reviews (believe me, I tried -- you should try that too some day!-).  Gonna edit tags to add the relevant compute engine one in.  BTW, serverfault IS really the right place for this Q & A!-)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I realize that now!

Comment: Note that Google's Cloud Platform docs link to Stack Overflow; I don't think they link to Server Fault?

Comment: @GregKrsak, yes we **do** "link to ServerFault" now! Check out https://cloud.google.com/support/ at Community Support.  We also sponsor and monitor 3 tags over there now.  I've been on this new tech support job for not even three months yet, so I don't think I've been all that slow in making it happen, though of course there's lot more to do, like *spreading the word* so everybody **knows** we love ServerFault (and sysadmins) just as much as StackOverflow (and developers)...:-).